# How to change the shape of the image file

Tags: numpy, image-processing, numpy-ndarray

(38, 224, 224, 3)
let say I have a image np.array looks like this 
I want to change the shape with (38,3,224,224)
how should I do it?

Comment: `np.moveaxis()` https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.moveaxis.html

Comment: if I want only select 38 how should I do?